# Horizontal Scroll DIV taking width of full page and not respecting the max-width tag

Tags: html, css

I have what I thought would be an incredibly simple setup...

You can imagine a div that is 400px high, fills the width of the container, and applies a horizontal scroll if the content inside is too wide...

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='img' src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x80'>
  <img class='img' src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x80'>
  <img class='img' src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x80'>
  <img class='img' src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x80'>
</div>
```

However, rather than getting a div that is maximum 300px wide which scrolls to accommodate the images which overflow on X (since they are inline-block and white-space:nowrap), the div expands to the combined width of the images, even if that means blowing right through other elements on the page, as if it just does not respect the content container it is within either.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Looks like it works to me.

Comment: Define width in some manner. I know IE11 freaks out if `width` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

maybe all you need is

```
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;  
}
```